# How to name graphic files for iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, graphics, iphone-5

The iPhone 5 has just launched, so I was wondering if anyone knows how graphics files are going to be renamed for the iPhone 5?

The resolutions are different between the iPhone 4S and the iPhone 5, so I assume there will also be a new naming strategy applied for iPhone 5 graphics? @3x maybe?

Comment: Would be very interesting, but there isn't any official information yet. But I do not believe it will be @2x since it doesn't change anything in the DPI. Just added some height, so I believe it will just get resized like it already happens when the status bar gets higher.

Comment: Well the launch image uses Default-568h@2x so perhaps that is the standard. Unsure without documentation

Comment: Yeah, that could be right, because it's just the height really, so perhaps I just need to space differently and change some graphics height (or something) to accomodate for the extra height.  Will wait a bit longer to see if anyone else has other info though..  thanks for the comments so far

Comment: Well actually, then it would not be able to tell the difference bewteen the iphone 4/S or iphone 5 when loading the graphics (?) and the phone 4/S display would then appear wrong.  There must be some type of system I would think...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006728/iphone-iphone5-support-to-existing-app/13025137#13025137

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iPhone 5 is still a Retina display, with two pixels for every point. That's what the @2x suffix for graphics is used to indicate, so the same suffix will be used here.

As others have suggested, there is one new piece of required artwork in the Default-568h@2x.png startup image, without which it appears your application will not be recognized as supporting the iPhone 5's display.

Beyond that, the only reason you would need special graphics for the iPhone 5 is if you had keyed something off of the overall dimensions of the screen. In that case, you'll need to detect the main screen's frame and substitute appropriate graphics at runtime using your own naming convention.

Comment: Thanks Brad, seems like this answer is the correct way for the moment - hopefully they introduce a similar naming scheme to the way they distinguished iphone 3 / 4 graphics from one another, it would be the most simple.

Answer (score 6):

`-568h@2x.png` scheme doesn't work right now for graphics other then splashscreen, so for today there's no way.

Comment: I can't find anything either, but surely there must be something out because I read somewhere that some of the larger app developers were given the opportunity to get their app graphics up to scratch to display properly on the new resolution screen!!!

Comment: for now I use different image mode. For example - I've got backgroud image. To fit both screen dimensions I use two files 640x1136 for retinas and 320x480 for non-retina. Image mode is set to Aspect Fill and everything is ok.