# iPhone - iPhone5 support to existing app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, iphone-5

Should i have to place a separate xib Like 1 for iPhone5 and 1 for iPhone4 and lesser Doing this way seems very bad practice.
Can any one have idea about it? Also iPhone5 Using Autolayout? i am not getting how Autolayout works.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702546/same-xib-for-iphone4-and-iphone5-possible

Answer (score 1):

Watch the WWDC 2012 Videos on the subject. There are three 1 hour videos that taught me all I needed to know in order to migrate my apps to Auto-Layout.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

Answer (score 1):

If your main issue is the new screen size make sure to add Default-568h@2x.png.
This 640 × 1136 image is needed for your app to utilize the iPhone 5's full screen.

Also use

`[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]`

to get the current screen's width and height. Do not hard code 320 width 480 height.

`CGRect aFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];`
`width=aFrame.size.width; height=aFrame.size.height;`

Comment: This makes sense, but as I said above, don't you think apple will create something easier?

Comment: Easier? Thats easy enough Ray. Ray its always better to make your code smarter to overcome simple obstacles such as this. Don't depend on apple making it easier. Will appreciate a 1 or a check Ray.

Answer (score 0):

seperate xib files: yes, is one of the possible ways.

autolayout: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

(google first hit).

Answer (score 0):

I modified my apps to include autolayout.  In all honesty, if I'd have been more proactive I would have designed them with new screen sizes in mind at the start - a mistake I won't make again!

How you approach it really depends on how you designed your original application.

Answer (score 0):

I found and will help others also:
https://github.com/mindsnacks/UIImage-MSImageNamed568hSupport

using this we can load 568h size image for iPhone5 if present o.w. load normal image great help...

Example:

```
#import "UIImage+MSImageNamed568hSupport.h"
.
.
IBimgViewBG.image=[UIImage ms_imageNamed568hSupport:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sample.png"]];
.
.
```

Note: include this images in your project

```
sample.png      // for earlier versions
sample-568h.png // for iphone5
```

Comment: Dude, you are basically doing the same thing I showed you below. The first two lines of code are               "const CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size; const CGFloat screenHeight = MAX(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);" Could of gave me a 1 :(